# Check if a shell variable has more than one line using built-ins?

Tags: bash, shell-script, string, posix

I can do this by calling the external utility `sed` (for a known non-empty `$myvar`) like so:

```
if [ "$(printf %s "$myvar" | sed -n '$=')" -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Your variable has only one line, proceeding"
else
  echo "Error condition, variable must have only one line"
fi
```

Is there a way to do this using only `bash` builtins?

Even better, is there a way to do this in a POSIX-specified manner, without calling external utilities?

---

(This question is one of curiosity and finding better ways to do things; the above code *does* function.  I'm wondering if there is a cleaner/faster way.)

Comment: With that function, the result of `myvar="ab"` is exactly the same as the result of `myvar=$'ab\n'`. Should a trailing newline be ignored?. In my opinion, it shouldn't.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, you are absolutely correct for the general case.  In my specific case, I was setting the variable in the first place using command substitution, so was guaranteed to have no *trailing* newlines.

Comment: So, if the variable has no trailing "new line" and contains no "new line" it should be counted as "one line". If a trailing "new line" is added, it should be counted as "one more", correct?. There is only one case left that the function with sed fails to process and in my opinion should be counted as "one line" (there are no "new lines" included in the variable). ... ... ... what if `myvar=''` or `unset myvar`?

Comment: @BinaryZebra, this is what I get for failing to assiduously reduce my code to a simplest case standalone example.  :)  The conditional line itself is taken from my actual production script; the `echo` lines are obviously filler.  Earlier in the script (just after the command substitution) I checked that the variable started with the expected pattern—so I already know the variable is not empty or unset.  This is my question post, not an answer, so I don't feel it's necessary to edit it at this point, but feel free to propose one if you see a simple way to make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, You need a "simplest case standalone example". :-) ... No edit needed, it is already becoming "an old question", but I took the liberty of proposing one :-) ... feel free to simply "reverse the edit" if you don't like it for any reason. I hope this is the end of the history for this question. Bye.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The POSIX way:

```
NL='
'
case $myvar in
  *"$NL"*) echo more than one line ;;
        *) echo one line ;;
esac
```

This also works in pre-POSIX Bourne-like shells, too.

Answer (score 7):

There are several options (bash first, POSIX is below).
The code inside each function could be easily used outside.

```
#!/bin/bash

nl=$'\n'

aregex   (){ [[ $a =~        $nl     ]]; }
apattern (){ [[ $a ==       *$nl*    ]]; }
acut     (){ [[ $a != "${a%%"$nl"*}" ]]; }
areplace (){ [[ $a != "${a//"$nl"/}" ]]; }
acase    (){ case $a in (*$nl*) true;; (*) false;; esac; }
aifs     ()( IFS="$nl"
             set -f; set -- x${a}x;
             (( $# > 1 ));
           )
aread    (){ IFS="$nl" read -rd '' -a b <<<"x${a}x";
             (( "${#b[@]}" > 1 )); }
```

Each function is an option. Each function will exit with a return value of 0 if there is only one line and a return value of 1 if the variable `$a` has more than one new-line (more than one `$'\n'`).

After a function is executed, this will print the line required:

```
out=''; "$function" && out="more than "
printf "%9s   = %sone line\n" "$1" "$out"
```

---

Executing all options:

```
a='ab'"$nl"'cd' ; alltests
a='ab  cd'      ; alltests
```

Gives this output:

```
   aregex   = more than one line
 apattern   = more than one line
     acut   = more than one line
 areplace   = more than one line
    acase   = more than one line
     aifs   = more than one line
    aread   = more than one line

   aregex   = one line
 apattern   = one line
     acut   = one line
 areplace   = one line
    acase   = one line
     aifs   = one line
    aread   = one line
```

## POSIX

The following options fail in POSIX for several reasons:

- aregex    : There is no regex `=~` operators in POSIX.
- apattern  : There is no `==` operator in POSIX.
- areplace  : Parameter expansion does not have the `${ / / }` option.

Four could safely be translated to POSIX:

- posixcut  : Probably the best solution.
- posixcase : A common solution for POSIX shells.
- posixifs  : Executed inside a sub-shell to be able to set `set -f`.
- posixread : read does not have `-d` or `-a` but it could be adapted.

---

```
#!/bin/dash

nl='
'

posixcut (){ [ "${a}" != "${a%%"$nl"*}" ] ; }
posixcase(){ case $a in (*$nl*) true;; (*) false;; esac; }
posixifs ()( IFS="$nl";
             set -f; set -- x${a}x;
             [ "$#" -gt 1 ];
           )
posixread(){ local b=0;
             while IFS=$nl read -r _; do
                 b=$((b+1));
                 [ $b -gt 1 ] && break;
             done <<-_EOT_
x${a}x
_EOT_
             [ $b -gt 1 ];
           }
```

**Note**: Yes, `local` is not strictly POSIX, but [is pretty well supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597697/posix-compliant-way-to-scope-variables-to-a-function-in-a-shell-script).
The local for `b`, could be safely removed (check for global `$b` usage).

## Bourne (1977 shell).

If you need code for the original 1977 Bourne shell, use this:

```
posixcase() { case $a in *$nl*) true;; *) false;; esac; }
posixifs () ( IFS="$nl"
              set -f; set -- x${a}x;
              [ "$#" -gt 1 ];
            )
bourneread()( b=0                ### A helper function.
              while :; do
                  if IFS=$nl read c && [ $b -le 1 ]; then
                      b=`expr $b + 1`
                  else
                      echo "$b"
                      break
                  fi    
              done <<-_EOT_
x${a}x
_EOT_
             )
posixread   (){ [ `bourneread` -gt 1 ]; }
```

The expansion `${a%% }` used in posixcut will not work in Bourne.
The posixifs needs to be divided in two parts to work in Bourne.
The read option needs mayor changes, but works correctly.
Its function is posixread, the bourneread is a required helper function.

All code for Bourne was tested to be working correctly with [heirloom shell](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html).

Comment: The 1977 Bourne shell had no functions. I'd expect those kind of redirections wouldn't work great there either. Redirection was quite buggy back then there. It's a bit pointless trying to be portable to such an old shell anyway.

Comment: IIRC, It didn't support `set --` either. It may have supported `set - $var`, but `set -` alone would still be the same as `set` (again from vague memory). There, you'd need `set x $var; shift`.

Comment: Testing on a PDP11 emulator running Unix v7, it looks like `set -` worked there. The need for `set x $var; shift` might have been for another shell. Note that `yash` at least doesn't support `set - $var`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I fully agre with your words: ` It's a bit pointless trying to be portable to such an old shell anyway.` .... Yes, `set --` was not there originally: [set -- was not implemented originally, but came with the second release of the Bourne shell.](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/set-.html). ... ... Yes `set x $var; shift` would be the usual workaround. ... ... ... ... Thanks for all your informative comments. Bye.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Where is Unix v7 (for pdp11) available?

Comment: Check [the Unix Heritage Society](http://www.tuhs.org/Archive/PDP-11/Distributions/)

Answer (score 6):

The following snippets works in `bash` (with and without the `-posix` option):

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/bash -posix
version_1 () { [[ "$myvar" = *$'\n'* ]]; }
version_2 () {
  local newlines="${myvar//[^$'\n']/}"
  [[ "${#newlines}" -eq 1 ]]
}
for test in version_1 version_2; do
  if $test; then echo many lines; else echo one line; fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that should work with all Bourne syntax / POSIX shells and uses only builtins :

```
if (set -f ; IFS=$'\n'; set -- x${myvar}x ; [ $# = 1 ]) ; then
  echo "Your variable has only one line, proceeding"
else
  echo "Error condition, variable must have exactly one line"
fi
```

If your shell doesn't support `IFS=$'\n'` (like `dash` 0.5.7), you can use instead :

```
IFS="
"
```

Comment: I think this you need to set `IFS` otherwise the answer is wrong: `sh -c 'a="x y"; set -- $a; echo $#'` prints `2` for me, `sh -c $'a="x y"; IFS="\n"; set -- $a; echo $#'` on the other hand prints `1`.

Comment: @Lucas Thanks for your comment, answer updated.

Comment: The `set -f` will apply to future commands. You need `set -f`; set -- $myvar`. Also `set -- $myvar` on a `myvar=$'\n\nx\n\n\n'` would split into 1 element. And `myvar=''` or `myvar=$'\n\n\n'` into 0.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks Stéphane, I originally used two `set` instructions when tolf I was missing `-f` but overlook the issue introduced by an edit that came later. I agree empty lines are still an issue with this approach.

Comment: @BinaryZebra no problem, the issue was tricky to detect.

Comment: Answer updated to fully solve the `myvar=$'\n\n\n'` problem.

Comment: @BinaryZebra with this last edit, an empty `myvar` becomes an issue...

Comment: @BinaryZebra With the last syntax, an empty variable leads to 1 (one line) while I guess the OP expects this situation to fail the test as it would fail with his/her sample script.

Comment: Ah! good point. I understand you now. But that is an obvious failure of the original test. The correct question that should be answered is: "how many new lines contain the variable". If it is zero, as in `myvar=ab`, then there is "only one line". How many new lines contains an empty variable?. ... ... ... In any case, if that is really required, a test for an empty `$myvar` could be added. Which I believe it shouldn't.

Comment: As is also incorrect that with that function with `myvar="ab"` is exactly the same as with `myvar=$'ab\n'`. Should a trailing newline be ignored?.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Bash parameter expansion as follows:

```
n="${myvar//[^\n]}"; if [ ${#n} -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Your variable has only one line, proceeding"
else
  echo "Error condition, variable must have only one line"
fi
```

Test Samples:

```
myvar="xxx"
myvar="xx\nxx"
myvar="xx\nx\nx"
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is about checking variable with built-in but I'd like to add a useful sed script.

```bsh
printf '1\n2\n' |\
 sed -n '${1p};2q' # pipe IFF there is only 1 line
```

You can pipe into this and it'll will output 1 line if input is one line and output 0 lines otherwise